kubelet.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/kubelet: No such file or directory
I am new to Kubernetes, And I am trying to run kubelet and I am facing huge difficulties. Need your help I tried to remove Kubernetes, and reinstall completly, but kubelet doesn't run at all.
    ismail@Ismail:~/cloud_monitoringapp$ sudo systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-05-20 02:11:16 CEST; 4s ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
    Process: 25239 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 25239 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 55ms

Here is the journalctl -u kubelet :
ismail@Ismail:~/cloud_monitoringapp$ sudo journalctl -u kubelet

mai 20 00:07:30 Ismail systemd[99411]: kubelet.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/kubelet: No such file or directory
mai 20 00:07:30 Ismail systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes Kubelet.
mai 20 00:07:30 Ismail systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
mai 20 00:07:30 Ismail systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mai 20 00:07:35 Ismail systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
mai 20 00:07:35 Ismail systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes Kubelet.

Here is journalctl -xeu kubelet :
ismail@Ismail:~/cloud_monitoringapp$ journalctl -xeu kubelet

░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit kubelet.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 34664 and the job result is done.
mai 20 02:19:16 Ismail systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit kubelet.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit kubelet.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 34664.
mai 20 02:19:16 Ismail kubelet[33317]: E0520 02:19:16.908408   33317 run.go:74] "command failed" err="failed to load kubelet config file, path: /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, erro>
mai 20 02:19:16 Ismail systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit kubelet.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
mai 20 02:19:16 Ismail systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit kubelet.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.

Here is the cat /lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service :
ismail@Ismail:~/cloud_monitoringapp$ cat /lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service
[Unit]
Description=kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
Documentation=https://kubernetes.io/docs/
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=0
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


The error unable to load "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" denotes the boot strapping process has not created necessary files.  When you run kubeadm init / kubeadm join these will create all the required boot strapping files required for the cluster and start the kubelet process automatically.    Please initiate the init / join process to start the kubelet

I've Tried, but it didnt work unfortunately. Finally, I removed all kube component and reinstall after few hours. It finally worked
